# Open command window via batch file when cmd.exe is blocked

Tags: batch-file, cmd, window, blocked

cmd.exe is blocked at school. However batch files runs normally and sometimes it's very annoying to type the command in the batch file, write pause>nul and run the batch file to execute a command. Is there anyway to input commands from the user and execute them as cmd.exe does?

Comment: I don't know, HOW cmd.exe is blocked. But worth trying: `start cmd`. This should start a new cmd-window (or not; depends...)

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
:Loop
echo %cd%^>
set /p cmd=SkYWAGz Enter Command to Run (Press Ctrl + C to exit)
%cmd%
Goto Loop
```

Your very own command processor

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, the code in the batch file would be `start`

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
@echo off
break off
title Command Prompt
cls
:cmd
set /p cmd="%cd%>"
%cmd%
echo.
goto cmd
```